# I have a for loop of qplots, how can you structure the plots individually using LaTeX code e.g adding captions to the plots

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

<<echo=FALSE>>=

for(i in 2:38){
print(my_plot_function(i))
}

@

\end{figure}
```

This is my code, but what is happening is that when I compile my PDF I only get the first two plots that fit on the first page and I do not get the rest of the plots.
I would like to have all of the plots on separate pages.

And how would I go about adding captions to each individual plot in the for loop.

Comment: The title of this Q does not (fully) match its contents. Anyway - Why are you forcing all plots into one `figure` environment? And if you want your plot "`[h]`ere", why are you using a `figure` at all?

Comment: sorry just learning at the moment, any help would be useful.

Comment: No worries, we're all learning. ;-) But what if you just delete the first two and the last line?

Comment: Is this part of a larger document with additional text and so on? Or do you just want to export figures to PDF?

Comment: Then the title of my PDF comes right at the end, but the plots are on separate pages which is nice. So I just somehow need to retain the structure.

Comment: @DylanDijk Can you try to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2706569) with some plots and a title?

Comment: @milanmlft Yes I want to have additional text. I can get the plots on separate pages if I follow CL instructions of deleting the first two and last line, but the plots come before the title.

Comment: @CL. yes, ill make one now.

Comment: Do your plots need a `\caption{...}`?

Comment: No I don't, I have a title for each which is sufficient. But just want the structure of the PDF to be retained.

Comment: I understand what I did wrong now, I positioned `\maketitle` incorrectly. Very stupid from me, sorry for wasting your guys time. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: So it now works if I remove `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`. But if I wanted to organise the layout of the plots how do I go about doing that. For example if I wanted the first plot on a different page to the title, can I simply just insert a page break.

Comment: `\clearpage` should do the trick.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz if I wanted to have captions for plots made within the loop how would I do this. Is there a way to have latex code within the chunk.

Comment: @DylanDijk Not tested, as there is no [mre] in the question, but you could probably just move the `figure` environment inside the loop (with `\begin{figure}[p]` to display them on separate pages) and then use `\caption{...}`

Comment: `<<echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE >>=
for(i in 2:38){
  \begin{figure}[p]
  print(my_scatter_plot_function(i))
  print(my_box_plot_pergroup_function(i))
}
@`   I tried this but it does not recognise \. I do not understand how you can enter latex code into an R loop.

Comment: @DylanDijk I think I have an answer for you. But for the future, please try to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2706569) and *do not* change the question after you posted it. (You are welcome to *refine* your question, but do not turn it into *another* question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<echo = FALSE, fig.cap = c("First, Second, Third"), results = "asis">>=
  library(ggplot2)
  for (i in 1:3) {
    print(qplot(x = 1, y = i))
    cat("Arbitrary \\LaTeX code! \\clearpage")
  }
@
  
\end{document}
```

You can use the [chunk option `fig.cap`](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots) to add captions to your plots. Note that this will wrap your figure in a `figure` environment, turning it into a [float](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-floats).

Use the [chunk option `results="asis"`](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#text-results) to be able to print arbitrary text (including LaTeX markup) into your document using `cat()`.